# undefined method `verified' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to apply this methond to @post.author in the view, but I get

`undefined method 'verified' for nil:NilClass`

```
def showVerifiedIcon(user)
  u = User.where(username: user).first
  if u.verified?
    '<i class="fa fa-check-circle verified-icon fa-lg"></i>'
  else
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to user methods on objects that you are not sure if they will be nil or not is to user try.
In your case:

```
def showVerifiedIcon(user)
  u = User.find_by_username(user)
  if u.try(:verified?) #will return nil if u is nil
    '<i class="fa fa-check-circle verified-icon fa-lg"></i>'
  else
  end
end
```

Comment: `User.find_by(...)` is more concise than `User.where(...).first`.

Comment: I personally don't like `try` and it looks like a code smell every time I find it in the code base. The reason is that when you use try you don't have any confidence if you have your object on not. It violates the 'Tell, Don't Ask Principle'.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't know whether `User.where(username: user).first` returns the object you're expecting or not.
If not that query will return `nil`, so in your next line you'd calling the `verified` method on `nil` causing the error that you see.

You should always guard yourself from situations where you are not sure your method might return `nil`. In your example it was easy to spot but in an architecture slightly more complex you might end up passing nil around several class before calling a method on it making debbuging extremely trickier.

Always check before doing calling any method:

```
def showVerifiedIcon(name)  
  '<i class="fa fa-check-circle verified-icon fa-lg"></i>' if user(name)
end

private

def user(name)
  User.find_by_username(name)
end
```

If `User.find_by_username` returns `nil` then your if statement will not render you html element

Comment: @Un3qual yes because I forgot to pass the user before :)
I've edited the answer